# How can I VNC to a machine that is using a Shared Internet connection from my iMac?

Tags: macos, networking, wireless-networking

I have a Windows XP machine that is connected to the Internet using a shared ethernet connection with my iMac. From my Macbook Air that is connected to the same router, I'm still unable to connect or even ping the Windows machine.

What settings or changes should I make to allow me to connect to my Windows machine from my Macbook Air?

Here is a drawing of my network setup:

[image]

**Edit**
I can ping my Macbook Air from my Windows machine successfully.

But get a Request timeout when I try to ping my Windows machine from my Macbook Air.

Comment: it'd be very interesting if you did some investigations with wireshark

Answer (score 0):

which computer or interface is 192.168.2.1? I guess an interface on your MAC?

Does your win xp machine gave internet access?  I wonder if there's some issue from your xp machine being on a different subnet to the other two.  I think that router-modem device won't support different subnets.

What you could do is change every device's subnet mask to 255.255.0.0  or put the XP machine on 192.168.1 with 255.255.255.0 so, all are on the same subnet.  Once they are all on the same subnet, then make sure the OS software firewall is letting VNC in e.g. port 5900, and that it is allowing ping(ICMP requests and responses) and you could allow all ICMP.

Here are two pics for enabling ICMP on the XP Firewall
https://readme.phys.ethz.ch/media/how_to_enable_icmp_echo_requests_ping_in_windows_xp_service_pack_2/winxp-sp2-ping-08.png

https://readme.phys.ethz.ch/media/using_backuppc_via_cygwin_ssh_on_windows_xp/windows-firewall-icmp-settings.png

Comment: If you look at my diagram, you will see that all machines are on the 255.255.255.0 subnet.

Comment: Nope. If your diagram is accurate, what it says is that the XP machine is effectively in a different subnet than the other two. The iMac is acting as its router/gateway, providing its IP address, etc. (imagine that in your diagram, instead of the iMac, you have another modem/router, and you'll get the idea). For this to work, you would have to enable some sort of port forwarding so that inbound connections get routed to the XP machine, and you'd probable have to mess with the routing table too. Wouldn't it be simpler to have the XP machine connect directly to the router?

Comment: @PaulJ If you are going to reply to somebody then use an @ sign followed by their name. You are replying to Trey ther so say so and with an @

Comment: @TreyCopeland 255.255.255.0 is not a subnet, it is a subnet mask. And it means that the first 3 octets are the network portion. That means that 192.168.1 and 192.168.2 are different subnets, with the same subnet mask of 255.255.255.0  However, if you had a subnet mask of 255.255.0.0 then they would both be on the same subnet, because their network portions would then be identical.

Comment: @PaulJ You write "For this to work, you would have to enable some sort of port forwarding so that inbound connections get routed to the XP machine," <--- Assuming he doesn't have double NAT then he wouldn't need port forwarding for communication within his LAN. Since you say he would need port forwarding, I wonder then, Do you think he has double NAT? Are you sure? How are you sure?

Comment: @barlop: just look at his diagram. The XP machine is hanging off the iMac, has an IP range different than the one from the main subnet… It looks pretty obvious to me. The iMac is acting as a router/gateway, and is creating its own subnet and NAT for the computers that hang off it (only the XP machine, in this case).

Comment: @PaulJ  Yes I can see the XP machine connected to the iMac and the different IP range, different subnet. But do you know you can have a router and also multiple subnets without NAT?  So i'm asking you *Specifically* what makes you sure that there's NAT on the iMac router?

Comment: @barlop: well, in pretty much every home network configuration I've seen, these things are done with NAT, so to me it's as reasonable as assuming that someone using Windows is using it with a mouse/trackpad (instead of, say, keyboard shortcuts). But if you want to be super-extra-pedantic about it... no, I don't know it with 100% certainty. Anyway, I think we're getting sidetracked here: I'm still curious about why the original poster can't simply connect the XP machine to the main router, which would be the simplest choice.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/19828/discussion-between-barlop-and-paulj).